# Multi line Text box max length

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i want to have `<asp:textbox>` and set it to multi line
but when i set to multi line maxlength property not work.
How to control `max length` of multi line `asp:textbox` by jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
<script>

        function checkTextAreaMaxLength(textBox, e, length) {

            var mLen = textBox["MaxLength"];
            if (null == mLen)
                mLen = length;

            var maxLength = parseInt(mLen);
            if (!checkSpecialKeys(e)) {
                if (textBox.value.length > maxLength - 1) {
                    if (window.event)//IE
                        e.returnValue = false;
                    else//Firefox
                        e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
        function checkSpecialKeys(e) {
            if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 46 && e.keyCode != 37 && e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 39 && e.keyCode != 40)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

    </script>
```

in HTML

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtComment" onkeyDown="checkTextAreaMaxLength(this,event,'150');" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression validator instead. This will work on the client side

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="valInput"
    ControlToValidate="txtInput"
    ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,100}$"
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a maximum of 100 characters"
    Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```